# How to configure Webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to configure Webpack to do some tasks automatically on my Wordpress website, but I'm not really sure about what I'm doing.
Basically I am making changes in the /src directory of my theme, and I expect Webpack to compile everything and update files in /dist directory. I'm using Mamp and seeing the results at the url localhost/portfolio

This is what I need:

1. Compile SCSS
2. postcss (for cleaning and prefixes mostly)
3. Minifying, compress and concatenate all css an js
4. source map
5. Image processing (sizes, formats etc)
6. Everytime that I save some file, I need to automatically update de files in /dist directory and refresh the browser
   This last point I think is a little tricky because I need it to work with Wordpress.

This is what i get so far, and not really sure about what I'm doing here:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");


module.exports = {
  entry: ['./src/index.js'],  //'./src/index.js' ya es la ruta por defecto, no haría falta ponerlo
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),  //dist ya es la ruta por defecto, no haría falta ponerlo
    clean: true //replace previous files with the new files from the new cycle of bundle
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(c|sc|sa)ss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
          },
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          // "style-loader",
          {
            // Translates CSS into CommonJS
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            // Compiles Sass to CSS
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin(),
      
      // For webpack@5 you can use the `...` syntax to extend existing minimizers (i.e. `terser-webpack-plugin`), uncomment the next line
      // `...`,
      new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
    ],
    minimize: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'styles.css'
  })
  ]
};
```

Any help? Thank you very much.